# Atribuir uma cor a imagem adicionada com "android:drawableLeft"

Tags: android

Tenho um devido caso que estou utilizando três imagens para cada um dos meus botões, como mostra abaixo as imagens:

- ic_palette_black_36dp
- ic_palette_red_36dp
- ic_palette_blue_36dp

**Código:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_palette_black_36dp"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_palette_red_36dp"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First Button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_palette_blue_36dp"
/>
```

**Screenshot**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma maneira de fazer isso, porém em Lollipop, Android 5. + é estabelecendo uma tonalidade em um `drawable bitmap`, desta forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:tint="@color/red_tint"/>
```

Estou utilizando [Android 2.3.3 Gingerbrend](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.3.html) e [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), portanto gostaria de encontrar uma solução sem usar alguma `lib`. É possível definir a uma cor para a imagem adicionada com o `android:drawableLeft` nestas condições? Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda da AppCompat, é possível, sim.

Dada a seguinte disposição...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pablo.tintdrawableleft.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botao_preto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="Botão preto"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botao_vermelho"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="Botão vermelho"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botao_azul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="Botão azul"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

... podemos usar a seguinte função pra obter o resultado:

```
private void pintarDrawableLeft(Button botao, int recursoDeCor) {
    Drawable leftDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(botao.getCompoundDrawables()[0].mutate());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(leftDrawable, ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), recursoDeCor, getTheme()));
    botao.setCompoundDrawables(leftDrawable, null, null, null);
}
```

O que estamos fazendo é: primeiro pegamos o drawable da esquerda do botão. Isso pode ser feito com a função `getCompoundDrawables`. Ela retorna um array de quatro posições. O `Drawable` da esquerda é o da posição 0. Depois disso, fazemos `mutate()` nele para evitar que a mudança de cor afete todos os outros usos da mesma imagem. Em seguida, usamos `DrawableCompat.wrap()` para "empacotar" nosso `Drawable` em um outro que permite o uso do `setTint`. Por fim, colocamos de volta o Drawable já colorido nos `compoundDrawables`.

*Observação: não está funcionando, por algum motivo, na API 16 (apesar de estar funcionando na 10 e na 23). Atualizarei assim que encontrar uma solução.*

Comment: Fala meu amigo, tranquilão! Pois bem, esqueci de mencionar que procuro uma solução para API 10 sem ter que inserir alguma lib. Mas logo abaixo na questão consta para funcionar em versões menor que Lollipop.

Comment: Mas não precisa de outra biblioteca. Só a AppCompat. Você não está usando a AppCompat? É praticamente obrigatório usá-la, se você quer dar suporte a versões antigas do sistema.

Comment: Trabalho num empresa que desenvolveu um app de uso interno a três/quatro anos atrás porém ainda não convenci eles a trabalhar com as versões mais modernas, mas estou trabalhando nisso. Então não queria adicionar `libs` para fazer apenas algumas alterações etc. O app não está no PlayStore, então eu acabei desenvolvendo um serviço para verificar detalhes dos dispositivos que estão sendo instalados. Ai vou ter uma estática para tomar algum tipo de decisão.Cara, para falar a verdade, até já resolvi o problema de outra forma, mas queria que alguém publicasse algo legal para eu poder dar os créditos

Comment: @CleidimarViana Você vai ter que praticamente reescrever a AppCompat para fazer isso. Eu compreendo sua preocupação em adicionar bibliotecas para pouca coisa, mas isso não é pouca coisa. A AppCompat é a biblioteca padrão (oficial) de compatibilidade. Sem ela fica até difícil dar suporte a versões novas sem quebrar as antigas. Ela já vem inclusa quando você cria um projeto no Android Studio, inclusive. Pra tirar ela tem que saber o que se está fazendo. Como o aplicativo não está na loja, isso é mais um motivo pra não ter que se preocupar com o tamanho.

Comment: De toda forma, sempre que você fizer uma pergunta assim, deixe explícito que não quer usar a AppCompat, para evitar esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Blz! Só esqueci de deixar explícito. Obrigado pela dica. Aqui a gente usar Eclipse e não usamos AppCompat. Unica `lib` mais atualizada em relação ao `Android developer` é `support-v4.jar`. As outras libs são para casos específicos. Abraços. Vlw